# Python - Identify groups of consecutive 0's and replace them

Tags: python, arrays, replace

Im trying to identify groups of n-length consecutive 0's (0, 00, ... 00000, etc.) in an array and then replace them with the average value from values before and after the run.

So let's say:

`a = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3]`

In this case, it would check the array, pick out the two runs and change them. The output should look like this:

`a = [1, 2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

I tried but it only applied it to the first instance. Is there any way to do this for the whole array (can be quite long)?

Comment: Could you post your attempt?

Comment: There is no automatic function for this, but it's not a hard loop to write.

Comment: Please share the code for your initial attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this handles it.

```
newa = []
span = 0
for n in a:
    # Is this number non-zero?
    if n:
        # Yes.  Have we just passed a string of zeros?
        if span:
            # Yes.  Average this value and the last non-zero value
            # and duplicate for as many zeros as we saw.
            avg = (newa[-1] + n) / 2
            newa.extend( [avg] * span )
            span = 0
        # Always add this number to the new list.
        newa.append( n )
    else:
        # No, this number was a zero.  Just count it.
        span += 1
```

Can this series end with a span of zeros?  Only you know whether that's a concern or not.

**EDIT** to ignore series longer than 5.

```
newa = []
span = 0
for n in a:
    # Is this number non-zero?
    if n:
        # Yes.  Have we just passed a string of zeros?
        if span:
            # Yes.  Average this value and the last non-zero value
            # and duplicate for as many zeros as we saw.
            if span > 5:
               avg = 0
            else:
               avg = (newa[-1] + n) / 2
            newa.extend( [avg] * span )
            span = 0
        # Always add this number to the new list.
        newa.append( n )
    else:
        # No, this number was a zero.  Just count it.
        span += 1
```

Comment: Im new to coding, so what do these spans mean. Also how can it be modified to detect groups that are less than 5 for example (ex. 2 consecutive zeroes and 4 consecutive zeroes)

Comment: `span` counts how many zeros in a row we have seen.  If I find a non-zero, and there was a string of zeroes before it (so `span` > 0), then we do the averaging and reset the zero counter.  If I find a zero, I just count it and don't add anything to the list until later.

Comment: I can't make it work for a max of 5 consecutive zeroes. I want it to apply this method to strings of 5 zeroes or less, and the higher groups to leave as is. How would I do it? Thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: You should have said so.  It's easy enough to modify it.

Comment: In one of the instances, the array is empty when It passes to the `avg = (new_sig[-1] + n) / 2` statement and throw up an `IndexError: list index out of range` how can I fix this?

Comment: That would mean you had a zero at the start of a sequence.  What is your rule in that case?  One hack would change `if span > 5:` to `if span > 5 or not newa:`, but only you know what the right process is.  That's the problem with unclear specs.